# My output is stuck on the same thing

Tags: java, switch-statement, break

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionThreeB {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 1, 2, or 3: ");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();
    switch (number) {
      case '1':
        System.out.println("You entered 1.");
        break;
      case '2':
        System.out.println("You entered 2.");
        break;
      case '3':
        System.out.println("You entered 3.");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("That's not 1, 2, or 3!");
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile and run the program I end up with the last output line ("That's not 1, 2, or 3!") as an output no matter what value I put in. I've attempted to use if then statements to fix this, it compiles but the result is the same

Comment: Remove the quotes around the `int` values : `case 1` , because `'1'` =/= `1` .

Comment: And you could if `if (number >= 1 && number <= 3)` instead of a switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `number` has type `int`. Switch statement is checking chars (number is in single quotes '1').

1 is not the same that '1'. You need to remove single quotes to compare ints.

```
public class QuestionThreeB {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 1, 2, or 3: ");
    number = keyboard.nextInt();
    switch (number) {
      case 1:
        System.out.println("You entered 1.");
        break;
      case 2:
        System.out.println("You entered 2.");
        break;
      case 3:
        System.out.println("You entered 3.");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("That's not 1, 2, or 3!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on your code, the input expects an integer while the case is in char (because of the ' single quotes). just remove it

```
case 1:

    System.out.println("You entered 1.");

    break;

  case 2:

    System.out.println("You entered 2.");

    break;

  case 3:

    System.out.println("You entered 3.");

    break;

  default:

    System.out.println("That's not 1, 2, or 3!");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java `int` datatype is completely different from `String` datatype. You are asking console for an int here: `number = keyboard.nextInt();` and then compare it with a String in `switch` statement which will never be equal. 
You have two choices: 1) Remove quotes from numbers in switch (as advised by Berger) 2) do `keyboard.nextLine()` instead of `keyboard.nextInt()`